# sinatra config.yml settings per environment don't work

Tags: ruby, sinatra, yaml, configuration-files

I tried to set up a config file for my sinatra app, and simple settings work. (the puts in my code prints "Hello!!") But I read [this document](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/config_file.html), which says I can define settings per environment. I tried it but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? ;)
I'm using this code:

```
#settings.yml
#environments: :production, :development
environment: :development

bla: Hello!!

development:
  db_adapter:   "sqlite3"
  db_location:  "db/development"
  db_logfile:   $stdout
  db_loglevel:  :debug
  haml: "format => :html5, :ugly => true"

production:
  db_adapter:   "sqlite3"
  db_location:  "db/production"
  db_logfile:   "log/production_db.log"
  db_loglevel:  :error
```

and

```
#main.rb
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'             #Webframework
require 'sinatra/config_file' #Config

set :environment, :development
config_file("settings.yml")

puts settings.bla

DataMapper::Logger.new(settings.db_logfile, settings.db_loglevel)
DataMapper.setup(:default, "#{settings.db_adapter}://#{Dir.pwd}/#{settings.db_location}")
...
```

It raises a noMethodError for settings.db_logfile...
sorry for my bad english ;)

EDIT1:
I got it ;)
I have to write this into my main.rb:

```
set :environment, :development

configure :development do
  set :db_adapter     ,  "sqlite3"
  set :db_location    ,  "db/development"
  set :db_logfile     ,  $stdout
  set :db_loglevel    ,  :debug
  set :haml           ,  :format => :html5
end
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You want to configure your environments like this:

```
configure :production do
  set :db_adapter, "sqlite3"
  set :db_location, "db/production"
  set :db_logfile, "log/production_db.log"
  set :db_loglevel, :error
end

configure :development do
  set :db_adapter, "sqlite3"
  set :db_location, "db/development"
  set :db_logfile, $stdout
  set :db_loglevel, :debug
  set :haml, {:format => :html5, :ugly => true}
end

configure :test do
  ...
end
```

see [Sinatra Readme](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra#configuration)

Comment: thx for the answer, it isn't right but it pointed me to the right direction ;)

Comment: it's correct, you don't have to set development. That's by default. If you deploy to Heroku for example it's set to production automatically throgh env vars.

Comment: I know, you just forgot to convert the yml syntax to the ruby one ;)

Comment: shoot, how could I have missed that? Your're right. That's totally unacceptable. Will have to reedit my post.

Comment: That is not recommended. I agree.

Comment: what are you talking about @kgpdeveloper? This has long been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Long Long time ago...

I think you haven't resolve anything if you load a config.yml file but set your configuration in your main file as i saw you do.

I had the same problem about noMethodError in settings.some_yaml_value and the reason was the path argument. I resolved in this way:

```
config_file '/config.yml'
```

note the /

Answer (score 0):

I was having the problem where the file was being loaded however the environment was not being picked up, so I would have to reference `settings.development.foo`

It turns out that if your `.yml` file contains any top-level keys that do not match your one of your environments then the whole environment loading is canceled.

BAD Example:

```yaml
defaults: &defaults
  foo: asd
  bar: xyz

development:
  <<: *defaults

test:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults
```

GOOD Example:

```yaml
development: &defaults
  foo: asd
  bar: xyz

test:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults
```